# How to remove List() and escape characters from response JSON in Scala

Tags: json, scala, playframework

I have the following function that takes in a JSON input and validates it against a JSON-Schema using the `"com.eclipsesource" %% "play-json-schema-validator" % "0.6.2"` library. Everything works fine expect for when I get an invalid JSON, I try to collect all violations into a `List` and later return that list along with the response JSON. However my List is encoded with `List()` and also has escape characters. I want to have the response JSON look like this:

```
{
  "transactionID": "123",
  "status": "error",
  "description": "Invalid Request Received",
  "violations": ["Wrong type. Expected integer, was string.", "Property action missing"]
}
```

Instead of this: (This is what I am getting right now)

```
{
  "transactionID": "\"123\"",
  "status": "error",
  "description": "Invalid Request Received",
  "violations": "List(\"Wrong type. Expected integer, was string.\", \"Property action missing\")"
}
```

And here's the actual function for JSON validation

```
def validateRequest(json: JsValue): Result = {

    {
      val logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger("superman")
      val jsonSchema = Source.fromFile(play.api.Play.getFile("conf/schema.json")).getLines.mkString
      val transactionID = (json \ "transactionID").get
      val result: VA[JsValue] = SchemaValidator.validate(Json.fromJson[SchemaType](
        Json.parse(jsonSchema.stripMargin)).get, json)

      result.fold(
        invalid = { errors =>

          var violatesList = List[String]()
          var invalidError = Map("transactionID" -> transactionID.toString(), "status" -> "error", "description" -> "Invalid Request Received")
          for (msg <- (errors.toJson \\ "msgs"))
            violatesList = (msg(0).get).toString() :: violatesList
          invalidError += ("violations" -> (violatesList.toString()))
          //TODO: Make this parsable JSON list
          val errorResponse = Json.toJson(invalidError)
          logger.error("""Message="Invalid Request Received" for transactionID=""" + transactionID.toString() + "errorResponse:" + errorResponse)
          BadRequest(errorResponse)

        },

        valid = {
          post =>
            db.writeDocument(json)
            val successResponse = Json.obj("transactionID" -> transactionID.toString, "status" -> "OK", "message" -> ("Valid Request Received"))
            logger.info("""Message="Valid Request Received" for transactionID=""" + transactionID.toString() + "jsonResponse:" + successResponse)
            Ok(successResponse)
        }
      )
    }

  }
```

**UPDATE 1**

I get this after using Json.obj()

```
{
  "transactionID": "\"123\"",
  "status": "error",
  "description": "Invalid Request Received",
  "violations": [
    "\"Wrong type. Expected integer, was string.\"",
    "\"Property action missing\""
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got the escape characters removed by modifying this line:

`violatesList = (msg(0).get).toString() :: violatesList`

TO:

`violatesList = (msg(0).get).as[String] :: violatesList`

Comment: See my comment in the answer below for the reason why this works.

Also, as a best practice, try to use .asOpt[T] instead of .as[T] to gracefully handle cases in which the input JSON is not as you expected.  Option is your friend. :)

Comment: @emote_control: Thanks for the explanation. However, when I change .as[T] to .asOpt[T] like `(msg(0).get).asOpt[String] :: violatesList` I get this error: `Expression of List[Serializable] does not conform to expected type List[String]`

Comment: Well, yes.  You'll be getting an `Option[String]` instead of a `String`, so you can't add it to a `List[String]`.  You'll need to handle that.  The advantage is that you don't get an error at runtime if one of your msgs is either null or not a String.  The disadvantage is that there's one extra step you need to take in order to flatten the List into just Strings that exist.

The quickest way to accomplish that is just declare `var violatesList: List[Option[String]]()` and then when you add it to the JSON object use `Json.obj("violations" -> violatesList.flatten).

Comment: Although with `Json.obj` you might have to declare `val violations = violatesList.flatten` and `Json.obj("violations" -> violations)` just to make the compiler happy.

ETA: ...because of the implicit conversions that Json.obj uses.

Answer (score 1):

What you want is a JSON array, but by calling `.toString()` on your list, you're actually passing a string. Play has an implicit serializer for `List`s to JSON arrays, so you actually just have to do less then what you already did - you can just remove the `toString()` part from `violatesList.toString()`.

In addition, don't create a map for your JSON and then convert it to a JSON, you can use `Json.obj` with a very similar syntax instead:

```
val invalidError = Json.obj("transactionID" -> transactionID, "status" -> "error", "description" -> "Invalid Request Received")
for (msg <- (errors.toJson \\ "msgs"))
  violatesList = (msg(0).get) :: violatesList
val errorResponse = invalidError ++ Json.obj("violations" -> violatesList)
```

Regarding your escaped quotes, I suppose it's because `transactionID` and `msgs` are `JsString`s, so when you convert them with `toString()` the quotes are included. Just remove the `toString` everywhere and you'll be fine.

Comment: I removed `.toString()` and now I get the following error:

`[error]  found   : List[String]
 required: String
[error]           invalidError += ("violations" -> violatesList)
[error]                                            ^
`

Comment: Please let me know if you can read that error properly, otherwise, I can make an edit on the actual question so that the error code is formatted properly.

Comment: Thanks! That worked, but the escape characters are still there. Please see my UPDATE 1. How do I remove them as well?

Comment: That makes sense. `msg(0).get` is of type `List[Object]` and if I remove the `.toString()` from it, it complains that objects cannot be written to a `List[String]`

Comment: Actually, transactionID and msgs are JsLookupResults, which is why you can call .get on them.  Since Play 2.4, the \ operator returns a JsLookupResult instead of a JsValue.  But calling transactionId.get returns a JsValue, instead of a JsString, because the content of the JsLookupResult can be any JsValue, and you haven't specified that you're expecting a JsString.  So you end up with a JsValue equal to "123", and when you call .toString on that, it interprets the "123" literally, and escapes the " characters.

If you know you have a String, use transactionID.as[String] instead of .get.

Comment: Or better yet, transactionID.asOpt[String], which won't throw an exception if transactionID is undefined for some reason.